# Prove that this set is bijective to the ultraproduct

Tags: functions, logic

Let $A$, $M$ be non empty sets and let $U$ be an ultrafilter on $A$. Let $M$ be finite an let $M_a$ = $M$ for all $a \in A$

for all $(m_a)_{a \in A}, (p_a)_{a \in A}$ $(m_a)_{a \in A} \sim (p_a)_{a \in A}$ if $\{a \in A| m_a = p_a  \} \in U$

Show there exists a bijection from $M$ $\to$ $(\underset{a \in A}{\Pi} M_a)/\sim$

Comments:
I understand all the notation, and have been working on this problem for a good bit of time, I guess the question is what would the quotient $(\underset{a \in A}{\Pi} M_a)/\sim$ be?

If $(\underset{a \in A}{\Pi} M_a)/\sim$ = $(m)_{a \in A}$ which i think it is, as if you relate it to any other $(m_a)_{a \in A}$ then you will end up in a contradiction as for example if $A = \{a,b,c\}$Then (1,1,1) if its related to (1,1,2) , (1,1,2) is related to (3,3,2) and then for $\{a \in A| m_a = p_a  \} \in U$ we have respectively {$a$},{$a,c$},{$c$} but $\{a\} \cap \{c\} = \oslash$ so then we have a contradiction as those cannot be elements of an ultrafilter (no empty set in an filter). So im thinking the quotient is just the set of all $(m)_{a \in A}$ (all the tuples where every element is equal). Is this the right thinking?

Answer (score 1):

What you've written is a bit confusing to me, but it seems broadly based on the right intuition: every element of the ultraproduct is in fact the equivalence class of some constant sequence. Specifically:

> For each $(m_a)_{a\in A}$, there is some $u\in M$ such that $(m_a)_{a\in A}\sim(u)_{a\in A}$.

Here "$(u)_{a\in A}$" is just the constant function always spitting out "$u$" - or if you prefer, the "$A$-sequence" all of whose terms are $u$.

To prove this we need to show:

> For each $(m_a)_{a\in A}$ there is some $u\in M$ such that $$\{a\in A: m_a=u\}\in U.$$

Thinking obversely, given $(m_a)_{a\in A}$ we get a *partition* of $A$ into a bunch of (possibly empty) pieces, one for each element of $M$: $$A=\bigsqcup_{x\in M}\{a\in A: m_a=x\}.$$

And this is where finiteness comes into play. How do ultrafilters interact with partitions of the domain into finitely many pieces?

> If $U$ is an ultrafilter on $A$ and $X_1\sqcup ...\sqcup X_k=A$ then exactly one $X_i$ is in $U$.

Taking the appropriate $u$ then gives the desired result.

Comment: Thanks that is really helpful: 
$(m_a)_{a \in A}$ creating a partition of A into a bunch of (possibly empty) pieces, one  for each element of M is exactly the idea I was looking for to tie together mine.

Comment: Because if its finite then, each partition is exactly one $Xi \in U$  (referring to your spoiler) which is related to a $(u)_{a \in A}$ (and so they are in the same equivalence class) as there are exactly $|A|$ many ultrafilters on $A$, each containing a unique $u \in A$. Am i correct?

Comment: to add to the previous comment, a unique $(u)_{a \in A}$

Comment: @Isomorphism420 No, that's not right. $A$ need not be finite (only $M$ is assumed to be finite) and if $A$ is infinite there will be *many* more than $\vert A\vert$ ultrafilters on $A$ (calculating the exact number is a good exercise). The point is that *regardless* of what $U$ is, there will be exactly one $u$ such that $(u)_{a\in A}\sim (m_a)_{a\in A}$. Of course this $u$ will depend on $U$, but that's fine.

Comment: Ok yes I understand, I see I wrote that incorrectly in my comment